# Keyboard shortcut to access the first link in a Google search page?

Tags: google-search, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut to access the first result in a Google search page?

Any "hacks" would be fine, as long as it does not require the mouse.

Comment: for a macOS only hack, see [this solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149533/129872) where you can use built in accessibility features

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Note: As of 2018 the answer is out of date. The triangle arrow next to the search result no longer appears.**

---

Assuming you mean the first search result, this is already built in to Google!

Notice there is already a little ▶ arrow will next to the first search result. Turns out pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> after your search will navigate to that first search result automatically – note that you may need to press <kbd>↓</kbd> first to set the focus to it.

If you don't want the first search result, press <kbd>↓</kbd> again to move the arrow ▶ to the next result, etc, until you get the one you want.

Then press <kbd>enter</kbd> to navigate to the search result with the ▶ arrow.

Additionally:

- pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> opens the search result in a new tab.
- pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> opens the search result in a new browser window.
- pressing <kbd>→</kbd> shows a screenshot for the given search result.

[image]

This is a fairly new change and was [rolled out with Google Instant Search](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=191139) in **September 2010**.

Comment: Pushing tab no longer seems to work (unless you push it 6 or so times), the best solution is to push down instead of tab to focus on the first link.

Comment: Not working anymore

Comment: tab of down arrow do not work anymore

Comment: Any update on what does work in 2018? Maybe an addon?

Comment: See the answer by @ap2051 below: it works in 2019.

Answer (score 30):

You can open the first link populated by Google search by pressing:
<kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>

After pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, a dialog box appears saying "Skip to main content"
[image]

Additionally, after pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> :

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> opens the search result in a new tab.
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> opens the search result in a new browser window.

Comment: **Note to everyone:** this is the method that works now (2019).

Comment: Now with "featured snippets", you might have to press Tab a few more times after pressing *Tab, Enter, Enter* to get to the actual link.

Answer (score 14):

When typing with suggest, down arrow to select a query and right arrow to select I'm feeling lucky option.

Shortcuts for when you're typing in the search box:

- <kbd>enter</kbd> will search for exactly what you typed in the search box.
- <kbd>tab</kbd> will update the query you’ve typed to match the first prediction.
- <kbd>↓</kbd> will highlight the next predicted query and show new results.
- <kbd>↓</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> will search for the highlighted prediction and points out focuses on the first result on the page.
- <kbd>↓</kbd> then <kbd>→</kbd> will take you to the webpage of your first result just like the "I’m Feeling Lucky" link.

http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=191139

Comment: That's basically not a shortcut. Too many steps.

Answer (score 10):

Hello from the year 2021. Google does not provide shortcuts (yet/anymore) to navigate through the search results.

However, there is a handy browser extension to solve the problem: [Web Search Navigator](https://github.com/infokiller/web-search-navigator)

[image: Web Search Navigator demo video]

Install links:

- [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-search-navigator/cohamjploocgoejdfanacfgkhjkhdkek) (5 out of 5 stars)
- [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/web-search-navigator/) (4.9 out of 5 stars)
- [Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/web-search-navigator/inkjbmhmeghalgpacijccmbmbclkjgop)

After installation you just press <kbd>↓ Down</kbd> and navigate through the results.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like [Pentadactyl](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/help/pentadactyl/)/[Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/vimperator) (Firefox) or [Vimium](http://vimium.github.com/) (Chrome) plugins is something for you?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine on a mac. It's much easier to do if you have a keyboard with numpad.

### Enable Alternate Control Methods for your Mac

System preferences >> Accessibility >> Alternate Control Methods. You can configure it to be enabled/disabled with 5 option taps. Alternatively you can also control the cursor with head movements or perform clicks with facial expressions.

[image]

You can move around with just the touch pad and then to select a link, just click. `5`. For more on this see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRZMZnCYIXA) and [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh27469/mac#:%7E:text=To%20quickly%20turn%20Mouse%20Keys,left%2C%20right%20or%20double%20clicks.)

Generally speaking The Mac OS has a lot pro keyboard features hidden inside its Accessibility. Some apps have their own accessibility features too.

Just make sure you adjust the cursor speed, etc. Otherwise it's going to be slow.

### Use down arrow key

The previous step can work all by itself, but it's ultimately slow. To accommodate for that, just scroll down using the arrow key.

The good thing is that if you're a little above the link or little below the link, still the cursor will consider that you're clicking on the link i.e. as long as you see the cursor changed to hand button then you should be able click.

And sometimes you might not be on the appropriate layer to scroll, so just try using `tab` or `cmmd+tab` to move around

<sub>I suppose Windows has similar accessibility features too, but unfortunately I'm just not much of a Windows user</sub>

## Alternate solution

Just hit `tab` and upon arriving the correct link, just hit `Enter`