# Google search "keyboard selector" disappeared

Tags: google-search

For me, the [little arrow discussed here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15945/keyboard-shortcut-to-access-the-first-link-in-a-google-search-page) has disappeared. Is there an easy way to select the first answer using the keyboard now? Is it possible to have those arrows back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, the arrow will be back & you can select the result.