# How to have keyboard shortcuts in Google Search not skip over results?

Tags: google-search, keyboard-shortcuts

Using Firefox 36; I look up this query in Google Search, with Javascript enabled for `google.com`:

https://www.google.com/search?q=something&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=something+pdf

Then I click on an empty area of the page with the mouse, and hit <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow. Instead of highlighting the first result with the triangle ►; it highlights the 3rd?

Then if I hit <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow again, it highlights not the 4th, but the 7th result??!

I've seen [Keyboard shortcut to access the first link in a Google search page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15945/keyboard-shortcut-to-access-the-first-link-in-a-google-search-page), and can't see anything there that would help with this; it seems this "jump"/"skip" with up/down arrows happens anytime there is a PDF file in the results - but I cannot see any logic behind it, it just seems to skip to a random result?

Which keyboard shortcuts can I use to highlight next/previous search result?